# Unable to send selected items in database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to send all selected items in database but unfortuantely the 1st selected Item is saving not the rest.

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddEVNT3" CssClass="form-control" SelectionMode="multiple" placeholder="Events">
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select Event--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="50 m flat race for Boys"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="Musical Chair"></asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem Text="Tug-of-war"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Penalty Shoot out"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Go as you like"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

And I wrote following code for save the data in database

```
Dim li As ListItem
 Dim evt As String = ""
   For Each li In ddEVNT2.Items
      If li.Selected Then
                    If evt = "" Then
                        evt = li.Value
                    Else
                        evt = evt & ", " & li.Value
                    End If
         End If
     Next
```

Comment: This code doesn't save anything to a database. Please try to write a [MCVE] when posting about code that doesn't work

Comment: Steve I want to store each selected  item in evt variable...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem

`Dim evt As String = ""
Dim li  As ListItem
For Each li In ddEVNT3.Items
If li.Selected Then
evt += li.Value + ",";
End If
Next`

Comment: Only 1 value is picking  but from next it's not entering in the loop.